# How do I find out the type of this map in a range based for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
map <int, map <int, double> > adj_list_M;
```

I want to run a range based for loop, iterating through this map. So I want to know the type I can use for getting the references of the elements.

Also please verify whether this is correct for doing that :

```
for( auto& ele : adj_list_M )
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _"...and using auto is risky..."_ can you add a bit to explain this ?  Also `std::map` has lots of type info available see __Member types__ - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Comment: The only risk I can imagine here is extra copy in case you will use `auto` instead of `auto&`, but it is already covered.

Comment: *"using auto is risky"* - um. huh ? that doesn't make sense. Then the type of a ranged-for iteration of an associative container (like a map) is always `std::pair<K,V>`. In this case `K` is `int`, and `V` is `map<int,double>`. Reference, const reference, value, as allowed, but that's the type.

Comment: @WhozCraig I tried for (pair< const int, map<const int, double> >& ele : adj_list_M), but threw a lot of errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "the elements"?

Comment: @WhozCraig No, that isn't right.  It is `pair<const K, V>`.

Comment: It's `pair< const int, map<int, double> >` . Only one `const`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type is  `pair`

the `[key, value]`'s template is

```cpp
template<typename _T1, typename _T2>
    struct pair
    {
      typedef _T1 first_type;    /// @c first_type is the first bound type
      typedef _T2 second_type;   /// @c second_type is the second bound type

      _T1 first;                 /// @c first is a copy of the first object
      _T2 second;                /// @c second is a copy of the second object
     ... ...
```

As key is always `const`, you can use the type below,
`pair<const int, map<int, double>>`
`pair<const int, double>`

```cpp
    map<int, map<int, double> > adj_list_M;
    map<int, double> a{ { 1, 1.1 }, { 2, 2.2 } };
    adj_list_M[1] = a;

    for (pair<const int, map<int, double>>& ele : adj_list_M) {
        cout << typeid(ele).name() << endl;
        cout << ele.first << endl;
        for (pair<const int, double>& subele : ele.second) {
            cout << typeid(subele).name() << endl;
            cout << subele.first << ":" << subele.second << endl;
        }
    }
```

output:

```cpp
St4pairIKiSt3mapIidSt4lessIiESaIS_IS0_dEEEE
1
St4pairIKidE
1:1.1
St4pairIKidE
2:2.2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through all the key value pairs in your container, try:

```
for (const auto& ele : adj_list_M)
{
    std::cout<<"First key in adj_list_M "<<ele.first<<std::endl;
    for (const auto& sub_ele : ele.second)
    {
        std::cout<<"First key in sub_map : "<<sub_ele.first<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Second value in sub_map : "<<sub_ele.second<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Of course, because of the `const` keyword, it is read-only. Remove the `const` if you want to edit the values in your key-value pair by reference.